# select 7-digit number in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there any possibility of reading a 7-digit number and if would be the 7-digit return back this 7-digits.

e.g.:

```
'Techo*nthenet techo*5684net* Tech4589317net techonthenet'
```

return: `4589317`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(my_column, '\d{7}') FROM my_table
```